# Is possible to use modern lists on Sharepoint on-premises?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, modern-experience, powerapp

I want to customize a list form using Powerapps.

In Sharepoint Online I can enable "new experience" of a list on list settings/advanced settings and the button "PowerApps/Custom form" appears on my list view.

I need the same behavior on Sharepoint 2016 on-premises, is possible?

Comment: probably on SP 2019 this will be possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this behavior will not ever be available in 2016. Of course using the Data Management Gateway from Microsoft you can connect to a SharePoint list on-prem and then use the PowerApp... app to fill out the details. There are certain limitations with connecting to SharePoint lists on-prem (as of this post) such as no access to MMS fields, though.